# MVVMCross Visibility Value Converter for UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross, xamarin.uwp

I'm using the MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.

I have the "xmlns:valueConverters="using:App.UWP.Converters"

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage.Resources>
    <valueConverters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="Visibility" />
    <valueConverters:InverseVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertedVisibility" />
</views:MvxWindowsPage.Resources>
```

I have the following bits of layout

```
<Button Content="Log In" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter{StaticResource InvertedVisibility}}" />
<ProgressRing Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource Visibility}}" />
```

My ViewModel has the IsBusy property

```
bool _isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return _isBusy; }
    set
    {
        _isBusy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy);
    }
}
```

When I change the IsBusy property, I get an exception thrown saying "Specified cast is not valid."

What do I need to do to get this to work?

EDIT for stack trace

```
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<RaisePropertyChanged>b__0()
   at MvvmCross.Uwp.Views.MvxWindowsMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(Action action, Boolean maskExceptions)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged[T](Expression`1 property)
   at intelliSPEC.Core.ViewModels.LoginViewModel.set_IsBusy(Boolean value)
   at intelliSPEC.Core.ViewModels.LoginViewModel.<Login>d__33.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxAsyncCommandBase.<ExecuteConcurrentAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxAsyncCommandBase.<ExecuteAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxAsyncCommandBase.<Execute>d__14.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code of your VisibilityConverter and InverseVisibilityConverter classes?

Comment: @MartinZikmund https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Plugins/Visibility

Comment: To make the converters work in UWP you have to implement native versions of those: `public class VisibilityConverter : MvxNativeValueConverter<MvxVisibilityValueConverter> { }`

Comment: See - https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters?#using-value-converters-in-windows-conventional-xaml-binding

Comment: Also make sure you bootstrap the plugin by adding a bootstrap class, the template for such cs file is here - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/nuspec/BootstrapContent/VisibilityPluginBootstrap.cs.pp

Comment: I have those classes setup just as you showed them already. Are you saying that I need to have an implementation also? I thought including the plugin, having the bootstrap, etc was sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed you have a typo in the first `Binding` - there is a missing `=` sign after `Converter`.

However, I think the main problem might be that you are using the MvvmCross converters instead of native ones. MvvmCross Value Converter is cross-platform solution that works on all platforms if you use the [Tibet binding](http://slodge.blogspot.cz/2013/06/tibet-binding.html).

However, if you want to use the native UWP Binding, you have to add a native windows wrapper around the converter, so that it implements the Windows-only `IValueConverter` interface, which is required by the API. To do this, first install the `MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility` package in both your Core and UWP project and then you just create the following classes somewhere in your UWP project:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : 
   MvxNativeValueConverter<MvxVisibilityValueConverter> { }
public class InverseVisibilityConverter : 
   MvxNativeValueConverter<MvxInvertedVisibilityValueConverter> { }
```

I usually place all such "native" classes in one file `Converters\NativeConverters.cs`, but that is just a convention. You don't have to provide any additional implementation for the classes. If you use the converters in your bindings, it should work as expected. I have successfully run your code this way.

Also make sure you create a bootstrap class in the UWP project:

```
public class VisibilityPluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader>
{
}
```

Comment: The = sign is a typo when I was typing out the post. I had the native converters already setup. I also already had the Visibility bootstrap setup.

Comment: I was wrong. I was using MvxValueConverter instead of MvxNativeValueConverter. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, that happens :-) . Glad it helped. Happy coding!